# Disable WordPress shortcode in one specific instance..?

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I have a plugin that utilizes shortcodes.  I am using this plugin on my own site, but I'm also trying to provide documentation with usage samples on my site.

When placing the shortcode on my page, though, it's actually triggering and displaying the shortcode output instead of the code example of the shortcode itself.

For example, when I have this...

```
[paypal_ipn_list field1="txn_id" field2="payment_date" field3="first_name" field4="last_name" field5="mc_gross"]
```

The shortcode is actually triggered because I'm using the plugin myself.  I need it to actually display that line, though, as a usage sample.

I tried replacing the actual []'s with ASCII values, so I used this...

```
&#91;paypal_ipn_list field1="txn_id" field2="payment_date" field3="first_name" field4="last_name" field5="mc_gross"&#93;
```

That actually displays that way, though, instead of converting to an actual [ or ] character.  So that's not good for usage sample purposes, of course.

Is there some way I can disable or escape these shortcodes in this one place so I can output the usage sample, but still allow them to function everywhere else where I may actually be using them myself?

Any information on this would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using the ASCII values in the *text* tab of the editor, rather than the *visual* tab? (I'm assuming this is where you're adding this)

Comment: The visual tab is the WYSIWG...isn't it?  I was doing this from the Text tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [escape shortcodes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Escaping) using a double bracket: `[[shortcode_here]]`

```
[[paypal_ipn_list field1="txn_id" field2="payment_date" field3="first_name" field4="last_name" field5="mc_gross"]]
```